# Play Multiple format Video, and audio file in Application

Tags: objective-c, video-streaming, avplayer

Hi I am developing Live TV and Radio mobile app. So I wanted to play multiple type video file in one player. Mostly Application play live streaming Video and audio files. I also wanted to play YouTube video also through player. So is there any library or sdk available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For video and audio files you can use [GUIPlayer](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=GUIPlayerView%20in%20ios%20github&*).

For playing youtube video you have to use [Youtube Player.](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)

In single custom you have to use the respected player